# Detrended Fluctuation Analysis

Tags: fractals

In the fitting procedure of DFA, how can we understand which order of DFA (Detrended Fluctuation Analysis) (DFA1, DFA2, and higher order DFA) should be applied in the time series?

Comment: You want to remove factors that you can reasonably explain, and look at what is left. Usually you can explain a linear trend; sometimes you can explain a second order trend. It's not very likely that you can formulate a reason to subtract a higher order fit.

Comment: You mean it isn't related to the order of time series? I mean There isn't any relation between time series properties and the order of DFA which should be applied?

Answer (score 0):

Paradoxically one may want to look at some measure of the correlations between the errors and the particular polynomial which you're fitting. Some orders of polynomials may have larger correlation coefficients than others, which lead you to the conclusion that that polynomial order may need to be included to 'detrend' the data... One suspects there is an optimal cutoff for which you begin to see diminishing returns the higher and higher order of polynomials which are included. This makes some sense until you realize that the Hurst Exponent is itself a measure of correlation, though I'm not all too sure you can utilize it to analyze the correlations produced in its use in DFA -- or maybe you can! Haha...

By the way, I'm no expert nor professional. So please take my advice with that proviso -- that is to say, sparingly...

Comment: "If the type of trends in given data is not known beforehand, the fluctuation function F(s) should be calculated for several orders p of the fitting polynomial. If p is too low, F(s) will show a pronounced crossover to a regime with larger slope for large scales s [8,9]. The maximum slope of log F (s) versus log s is p + 1. The crossover will move to larger scales s or disappear when p is increased, unless it is a real crossover in the intrinsic fluctuations and not due to trends [8]. Hence, one can find p such that detrending is sufficient." From - 'Comparison of detrending methods for FA'.